# Spring cloud stream artemis binder concurrency not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream, activemq-artemis

I have set up a spring cloud stream with an Artemis binder https://github.com/snowdrop/spring-cloud-stream-binder-artemis. I have two applications i.e a producer as well as a consumer. Below is my application.yml configuration

Producer config

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  cloud:
    stream:
      poller:
        fixed-delay: 5000
      bindings:
        sourceForBroker-out-0:
          destination: exchange
      function:
        definition: sourceForBroker
```

Consumer Config

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        r1:
          destination: exchange
          group: group1
          consumer:
            max-attempts: 1
            concurrency: 10
      function:
        bindings:
          r1Consumer-in-0: r1
        definition: r1Consumer
```

Everything working fine i.e producer sent data to the queue and the consumer is able to process data but concurrency is not reflected. when I check the Artemis console I see there is only one consumer. Attached console screenshot

[image]

Comment: This binder is maintained separately by the community. It is better to reach out to them on GH and file an issue there maybe.

Answer (score -1):

One producer can have many consumer. Your consumer is one only that's why it is showing one thread only.

Comment: That's not correct. I have discussed the same with one of the contributors to the Artemis binder. He has fixed it https://github.com/snowdrop/spring-cloud-stream-binder-artemis/pull/33